# Aplicar NDVI a imagens com OpenCV e Java

Tags: java, opencv

Galera, boa tarde.

Estou precisando de um help com processamento de imagens utilizando a biblioteca OpenCV. Basicamente preciso pegar uma imagem de satélite e aplicar o NDVI (índice de vegetação por diferença normalizada) seu cálculo é simples:

```
NDVI = (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)
```

Aonde NIR (*Near Infra-Red*) é a imagem da banda 5 que é infravermelha e RED é a imagem da banda 4, que é vermelha.

Porém após aplicar essa fórmula não tenho nenhum resultado a não ser uma imagem de fundo preto. Se alguém poder ajudar, valeu.

Mais informações neste link: http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6330-howto-ndvi.jsp

Comment: Bem, eu não entendo nada de opencv, então perdoe-me a minha ignorância, mas o que vem a ser NIR e o que vem a ser RED? Acho importante sabermos para podermos elaborar uma resposta. Além disso, após o NDVI ter sido calculado, o que exatamente você quer dizer por aplicá-lo? Qual é o algoritmo que você usa para aplicar o NDVI?

Comment: NIR = é o infravermelho próximo e corresponde a banda 5 do satélite landsat 8, RED = é literalmente vermelho e corresponde a banda 4 do satélite citado, APLICÁ-LO = pega se as imagens referente a banda 5 e 4 e joga na formula. Em relação ao algoritmo veja neste link: http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6330-howto-ndvi.jsp

Comment: Legal, não conhecia isso. Você pode confirmar se o OpenCV está de fato lhe fornecendo uma imagem, e não apenas um monte de preto? Além disso, seria interessnte você postar uma imagem exemplo que você quer processar bem como o seu código em Java. Dessa forma podemos tentar encontrar o que está errado no seu código.

Comment: Se você postar uma imagem em NIR e uma em RED, eu bolo facinho um programinha em Java para gerar o NDVI. :)